# Sveltekit: How to access locals on server side $lib functions

Tags: sveltekit

I am storing user information in hooks.server.ts :

```js
// hooks.server.ts
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    event.locals.user = { name: 'Bob the Cat' };

    return await resolve(event);
};
```

Now purely on server side, I can access locals.user on load function, but I am trying to access locals from a deeply nested $lib library. Up to now I need to pass locals.user on every intermediate function until it reaches the final function.

Is there a way of accessing locals from anywhere in the $lib folder? like a store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is easily possible. Everything is coupled with the current request so you cannot just make parts of that global without running into issues as soon as any code is asynchronous.

You could possibly restructure everything using dependency injection (all functions become instance functions of classes which are automatically constructed with dependencies like the current request). That way "in-between" classes do not need to have that dependency as long as the entire tree is constructed by the injector.

> like a store?

Stores have nothing to do with being global, *any value* directly exported from a module is "global" in the sense that it can be imported from anywhere; this is not specific to stores, they just add reactivity.